# CoffeeScript Compile On Windows With NodeJS

Tags: command-line, coffeescript

I have installed nodejs, installed coffee using npm and registered the environment variables and am now ready to compile my CoffeeScript into JavaScript for the first time.

I am running the following command in `c:\MyCoffeeScriptProject\`

```
coffee --compile --output js/
```

What happens next is that I get the interactive window and nothing in the "js" folder.

```
coffee>
```

I was expecting all `.coffee` files to be compiled into the "js" folder as `.js` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't tell it which files to compile.

```
Usage: coffee [options] path/to/script.coffee [args]
```

Append a single period to the end for the current directory.

```
coffee --compile --output js/ .
```

It's easier to read if you rearrange it though.

```
coffee --output js/ --compile .
```

compiles all coffee files in `.` to `js/`

A common usage pattern is to have a `src` folder.

```
coffee --output js/ --compile src/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c:/parent>coffee --output output  --compile src
```

Where "output" is blank folder and "src" folder contains coffee files.
Execute the command at level of src.